# Does a player get credit for a kill if an environmental block actually does the final kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Working on a guardian farm, and I'm not certain about the mechanics here.  Will I get credit for the kill if I am able to hit the guardians once, but let the campfire under the guardians, or the lava they're swimming in take the final kill?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only if you've hit the Guardians about 5 seconds before they die, no matter how they do it (e.g. death from fire, lava, suffocation, other mobs, etc.). Be careful, though, as cactus, fire and lava might destroy their drops too.

Comment: Yeah, I use campfires for the kill as they're a partial height block, and hoppers underneath will take the drops before they're destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the kill. If you are using a looting sword it will give the extra loot as long as you are the only entity damaging it. If this is not helpful say something.